# Qt / thread event loop QTimer/MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, macos, qt

I am coding an application on Mac OS X  / Qt. 
I have a thread with an event loop. In this thread I make MySQL queries each tick (called by a qtimer).

Randomly my application crashes with the following backtrace:

```
#0  0x00e27acd in QMutex::lock ()
#1  0x00f5842d in QMetaObjectPrivate::connect ()
#2  0x00f5897f in QObject::connect ()
#3  0x0134c230 in QMYSQLResult::QMYSQLResult ()
#4  0x0134c2d9 in QMYSQLDriver::createResult ()
#5  0x0006daae in QSqlDatabase::exec ()
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: We would need more information than that... for instance, what is trying to execute inside the lock function that it crashes on?  Does Qt output any debug information (it will usually do so when you mess things up)?  Any other information you think might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that you setup the MySQL connection from the same thread as you perform the MySQL queries from.